# How to show email sent notification ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've a mail controller which successfully sends email.

But I want to show a notification of "Email Sent Successfully" as the email is sent. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What mailcontroller are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MFMailComposeViewController`, you can use its delegate method.

**1.** Set the delegate: `mailController.mailComposeDelegate=self;`

**2.** Then use the delegate method `

```
 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
   if(result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
  {
      UIAlertView*sentalert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Sent succesfully!" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      [sentalert show]; 
      [sentalert release]; // if not using ARC
  }

  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //Dismiss your mail controller
}
```

Comment: Remember to release your alert ;)

Comment: @Cupcake, too used to `ARC` :D, ya will add that up.

Comment: Just a thank you to all Stack Overflow members. This is the best website and u ppl are the best!